# How to use GoogleMobileVision in real time frame capture?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, swift3

I am trying to detect smile probability in real time. Using GoogleMobileVision, but app is getting a crash due **options** parameter I am passing in GMVDetector.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue intValue]

Also when I am passing option as nil it is giving memory issue.

My Code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileVision

class ViewController: UIViewController, FrameExtractorDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var lblSmiling: UILabel!
var frameExtractor: FrameExtractor!
var faceDetector = GMVDetector()

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func flipButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    frameExtractor.flipCamera()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    frameExtractor = FrameExtractor()
    frameExtractor.delegate = self
    let options: NSDictionary = [GMVDetectorFaceLandmarkType: GMVDetectorFaceLandmark.all, GMVDetectorFaceClassificationType: GMVDetectorFaceClassification.all, GMVDetectorFaceTrackingEnabled: true]

    self.faceDetector = GMVDetector(ofType: GMVDetectorTypeFace, options: options as! [AnyHashable : Any])
}

// Getting individual frame image here
func captured(image: UIImage) {
    processImage(image: image)
    imageView.image = image
}

func processImage(image: UIImage) {

    let faces : [GMVFaceFeature] = faceDetector.features(in: image, options: nil) as! [GMVFaceFeature]

    for face in faces {

        if face.hasSmilingProbability && face.smilingProbability > 0.4 {
            lblSmiling.text = String(describing: face.smilingProbability)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot and using flag I solved it my self, 
Here is my working code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileVision

class ViewController: UIViewController, FrameExtractorDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var lblSmiling: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var newView = UIView()
private let ssQ = DispatchQueue(label: "process queue")
var frameExtractor: FrameExtractor!
var faceDetector: GMVDetector?
var faces = [GMVFaceFeature]()
var imgIsProcessing = false
var sessionCountToClr = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    frameExtractor = FrameExtractor()
    frameExtractor.delegate = self
    self.faceDetector = GMVDetector(ofType: GMVDetectorTypeFace, options: [GMVDetectorFaceLandmarkType: GMVDetectorFaceLandmark.all.rawValue,
                                                                           GMVDetectorFaceClassificationType: GMVDetectorFaceClassification.all.rawValue,
                                                                           GMVDetectorFaceMinSize: 0.3,
                                                                           GMVDetectorFaceTrackingEnabled: true])
}

@IBAction func flipButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    frameExtractor.flipCamera()
}

func captured(image: UIImage) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.processImage(image: image)
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}

func processImage(image: UIImage) {
    if imgIsProcessing {
        return
    }

    imgIsProcessing = true
    ssQ.async { [unowned self] in
           self.faces = self.faceDetector!.features(in: image, options: nil) as! [GMVFaceFeature]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.faces.count > 0 {
                    for face in self.faces {
                        let rect = CGRect(x: face.bounds.minX, y: face.bounds.minY+100, width: face.bounds.size.width, height: face.bounds.size.height)

                        self.drawFaceIndicator(rect: rect)
                        self.lblSmiling.text = String(format: "%.3f", face.smilingProbability)
                    }
                    self.sessionCountToClr = 0
                }
                else {
                    if self.sessionCountToClr == 30 {
                        self.newView.removeFromSuperview()
                        self.lblSmiling.text = "0.0"
                        self.sessionCountToClr = 0
                    } else {
                        self.sessionCountToClr+=1
                    }
                }
                self.imgIsProcessing = false
            }
        self.faces = []
    }
}

func drawFaceIndicator(rect: CGRect) {
        newView.removeFromSuperview()
        newView = UIView(frame: rect)
        newView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        newView.alpha = 0.3
        newView.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
        newView.layer.borderWidth = 4
        self.view.addSubview(newView)
}
}
```

I have uploaded my entire project on [github](https://github.com/niekzy/GoogleMobileVisionFaceDetectionDemo) feel free to use

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using some optional value, you need to write this code after that it will work.

```
let options: NSDictionary = [GMVDetectorFaceLandmarkType: GMVDetectorFaceLandmark.all.rowValue, GMVDetectorFaceClassificationType: GMVDetectorFaceClassification.all.rowValue, GMVDetectorFaceTrackingEnabled: true]
```